# Deploy the same version file in BPEL SOA

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

We have implemented a BPEL solution in a project, we are using human workflow for managing the task.
As we are facing a lot of changes in project so we are creating new version of SAR file. for every change when we created the new version(version count will keep increasing)

and if I will deploy the same version again the existing task will be state,

so we can not query those task in Human work flow API.

the problem with increasing the version is while restarting the server. its taking too much time to load those versions. I have nearby 20 process and its taking 20 minutes to load the process after starting the server.

Is there any way where we can deploy the same version again and again.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Using Oracle? ;) so please add a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume , it's Oracle and if so here is what you can do.

When you deploy through JDeveloper, you have an option to "override" existing version. By enabling this you can override the same version without need to deploy new version everytime.

Comment: Yes correct but I will loose all my task what I created in my current process. The problem is all task will be STALE if  I will do the same.